# Failed to use cout function in C++

Tags: c++, printing, cout

I'm a novice on C++, and I failed to run my first C++ program, the code is

```
     #include <iostream.h>
　　　void main() 
　　　{
　　　　　cout>>"Hello world!">>endl；
　　　}
```

but it failed to print `"Hello world!"` on the console, I'm confused on this issue for hours, and there seems not wrong with the configuration, I'm using Visual C++ 2010 Express and it's the basic console project format, can anyone help me?

Comment: just a few notes: includes from the standard library should not carry the .h: `include <iostream>`. IMHO I cannot recommend pulling everything from std into the current namespace `using namespace std` (which seems to be missing in your code snippet). Rather qualify with the namespace `std::cout` or use a namepsace alias to shorten things. Besides, you should change `>>` into `<<`.

Comment: Pulling everything into global namespace from std is not required when you include .h version of that header, in most cases.

Comment: Also, `main` should return `int`; that is, use `int main()` and not `void main()`. Add `return 0;` (or another appropriate value) just before the closing brace for `main`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have your direction wrong.

```
cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
```

Think of `<<` as pushing data into `cout`, i.e. the output.

Inversely, you use `>>` with `cin` to push data into a variable, from input.

Comment: @Breakinen - Back when I learnt C++ this was the first thing that stumped me, too. It's nice to see I'm not the only one!

Comment: @DeadMG - Whilst `void` isn't the ideal return type, it will compile and not cause any real issues. Figured that switching to `int` wasn't the most important thing to point out.

Answer (score 1):

You should enable all warnings and debugging information on your compiler.

The "double arrow" should go to the stream since it is an output, so you should probably say

```
 std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

1.

`#include <iostream.h>` is outdated. 
*thinking in C++* says it is equivalent to

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

But the latter is the prevailing one.

2.

as stated by others, you should use
`cout<<"Hello world!"<<endl`

3.
use `;` instead of `；`

To be clear, I guess 2 is your major problem and 3 maybe a typo while 1 is an advice

Comment: Thank you for your kind advice! It's amazing that you noticed the wrong semicolon^^